# How to disable ''Press ENTER or type command to continue" when I execute `write !xsel -b`

Tags: vim, pipe

My vim doesn't shipped with `+clipboard`, so I could not use like `"+y` commands to copy and paste with clipboard.

I want to map  to copy the text to clipboard, which is

```
vnoremap <C-c><C-c> :write !xsel -b<CR>
```

however, it will shows "Press ENTER or type command to continue", which is boring. How should I disable the message?

Comment: I'm not sure you can, but add one more `<CR>` to your mapping and it should skip passed it

Comment: @Thor Yes, adding an extra `<cr>` at the end of the mapping works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`:silent`](https://vimhelp.org/various.txt.html#%3Asilent) command to suppress that output.

There's a small issue in doing that in a `vnoremap`, since that adds a `'<,'>` range to your command, but that needs to be a range for `write` and not `silent`, so use `<c-u>` to delete that added range at the start and then add it explicitly after the `silent`.

Putting it all together:

```
vnoremap <C-c><C-c> :<c-u>silent '<,'>write !xsel -b<cr>
```

---

Another possible solution is to add an extra `<cr>` to the end of the original mapping, to go past the "Press ENTER" prompt:

```
vnoremap <C-c><C-c> :write !xsel -b<cr><cr>
```